# Fix $k >1$. How to prove that $\frac{n}{k^n} \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$ and conclude that $n^{1/n} < k$ for $n$ large enough.

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, inequality

Fix $k >1$. How to prove that $\frac{n}{k^n}\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$ and conclude that $n^{1/n} < k$ for $n$ large enough?

Comment: Is your sequence a decreasing sequence? Does it have a convergent subsequence?

Answer (score 2):

Since $k>1$, you can write $k=1+p$ with $p>0$ and use the binomial theorem:
$$(1+p)^n = 1+np+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}p^2+\cdots > \frac{n(n-1)}{2}p^2$$
So you have:
$$\frac{n}{k^n} = \frac{n}{(1+p)^n} < \frac{n}{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}p^2} = \frac{2}{(n-1)p^2} \overset{n \to \infty}{\longrightarrow} 0$$
Now if $\tfrac{n}{k^n} \to 0$, then surely $\tfrac{n}{k^n} < 1$ for $n$ sufficiently large, hence...

Comment: Your expression allows an explicit value for k to be gotten.

Comment: It would be better to replace $e$ with some other letter since $e$ usually stands for a certain well known constant...

Comment: @5xum good suggestion, I replaced $e$ by $p$.

Answer (score 1):

Using d'alembert,
$$\lim_{n\to \infty }\left|\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}\right|=\frac{1}{k}<1$$
and thus $\lim_{n\to \infty }x_n=0$ where $x_n=\frac{n}{k^n}$. 
Talking $\varepsilon=1$ in the defintion of the limit will gives you your second result.